# Batch "Set" command set other commands into the variable when used in a single line command

Tags: batch-file

Eventually I'm trying to make a batch file to auto generate the source files in my Java source file folder using "dir", replace single backslash with double backslash and add double quotes at the start and end of each output from dir.

Please do not ask why I don't use an IDE or a build tool, that's not the point here.

```
(for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s /c *.java') do @("@set var=%%f:\=\\%%"; @echo %var%)) > sources.txt
javac -cp ".\apis\*;." -d "." @sources.txt
```

It wasn't working the way I wanted it to. sources.txt is entirely empty. I know it's because "@set", but that means @echo wasn't working.

When I tested the first line in cmd, I found that @set also set all the stuff behind the semicolon into the variable. How can I get a break point for the @set command?

Comment: You cannot do string substitution on a FOR meta variable. You have to assign it to a normal environmental variable first. Have no idea what you are trying to do with the semicolon.

Comment: never said that. I said you have to assign the for meta variable to an environmental variable first. Then you can manipulate the environmental variable. The syntax is clearly defined in the help file for the set command. It never shows an example of manipulating a for variable.

Comment: To separate the set command with the echo command?

Basically I'm not a pro in batch, if it's more complicated than a C++ program I'd rather do that. But here I'm just asking why wouldn't it work?

I'm not going to save the environmental variable anyway, AFAIK it's temporary right?

Comment: I'm making another variable from the for variable. If I did that wrong can you tell me how to do it properly? :D

Comment: Variables only survive the current environment that the script was launched from. Once it closes they are gone.

Comment: It's fine if it's temporary, but the problem is that the set variable sets the whole thing, `<dir output>:\=\\%%"; @echo %var%` as %var%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do string manipulation on a `FOR` meta-variable.  It must be assigned to an environmental variable first.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s /c *.java') do (
    set "var=%%f"
    echo !var:\=\\!
))>sources.txt
javac -cp ".\apis\*;." -d "." @sources.txt
```

Comment: @m31317015, it is one of the most common problems with people new to batch files. I have literally answered that 4 times today alone.  If you search StackOverFlow you will find plenty of information. The code I gave you should work just fine without the quotes.  If you need the quotes in your file then that is fine. But you are making it sound like the code doesn't work without it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I need the quote since my folder has spaces in it. Quickly editing it now.

Oh and well, this is kind of embarrassing but I myself don't really search up here very often. I know here would be a helpful place but I tried not to, kinda like a double-edge sword. If I rely on here too much it would just be harmful.

And thanks for the help with this kinda newbie batch question. :D